# VB Web Reference works on local browser, but errors BC30002 not defined on webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, iis

I have an aspx page that works great with my wsdl Web References when running on my own machine/browser (right click, show in browser).

However, when I copy the files to a subfolder on the website, the compiler throws this error

BC30002: Type 'generalWS.general' is not defined.

where generalWS is the name of my Web Service.

The webserver has an older version of .NET (IIS6 says 2.0.50727).
My machine has .NET 4.0 (hard for me to tell actual version number).

Is there something I need to install on the webserver to make this run correctly?

Comment: Is your web service built in 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed .NET 3.5 on the server machine and this issue was resolved. I was targeting and testing on a .NET 3.5 machine and deploying to a .NET 2.0 machine.